# How to process bundled HTTP requests with ASP.NET WebAPI 2.0?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

On client side we have a lot of logic with nested http requests like:

```
$http.get('api/controller1/GetMarketData?marketId=' + ...).success((data1) => {     
....
                    $http.get('api/controller2/GetTypeInfo?typeId=' + ...
```

That's obviously very bad considering reliability, performance, code quality, etc.
I have the idea to put all requests in array and run it at once.
The only thing I don't know is how to dispatch them on server side with WebAPI?
The array will go to some general ApiController and what then?

Answer (score 1):

what do you mean by how to dispatch them?your server code should remain the same, no matter if your calls are made in a series or in parallel if you need to run your calls in parallel and not move on until are al finish you can use $q and the promises version of the $http service,  something like:

```
var arr=[];
arr.push($http.get('url1').then(function(response){return response.data}));
arr.push($http.get('url2').then(function(response){return response.data}));
arr.push($http.get('url3').then(function(response){return response.data}));
return $q.when(arr)
.then(function(result1,result2,result3){
    //do something here
})
```

this only works if your calls are not related if they are you need to do this for the ones that do not relate and are run in parallel and so something like

```
var arr=[];
arr.push($http.get('inpedent url1').then(function(response){return response.data}));
arr.push(
   $http.get('independent url2')
     .then(function(response){return response.data})
     .then(function(result2){
        return $http.get('url3 dependes on result2')
         .then(function(response3){
             return {response2: response2, response3:response.data}
          })
     }
);

return $q.when(arr)
.then(function(result1,result2){
    //do something here
})
```

this works for related calls and only needed if want to get a handle on all the responses, if you only care about the final result you can just change promises with out nesting it.

i suggest some reading on promises and angulars $q service

Comment: Your suggestion is good for client side. Unfortunately it still leads to many http requests. Yes, requests are independent.

Comment: I'd wanted to create kind of wrapper controller on server side which will dispatch the items/subrequests of the array by already existing controllers.

Comment: you don't need to, you can handle the requests independently, if your business logic states that all those calls have no use by them selves then you might want to rethink your api architecture